# Gwt Crypto - Odd exceptions caused by decryption taking too long?

Tags: java, encryption, gwt, exception

I am getting some really odd errors using Gwt-crypto. When I try to load a playerId from preferences I do the following:

```
public long loadIdFromPref(){
        Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences(HelperKeys.Preferences.GAME_PREFS);
        String secret = decryptString("ab0c441ca9dbd026bbb98a588e7d34d579dd00c326fbd38a");
        Long value = Long.parseLong(secret);
        return value;
    }
```

DecryptString method:

```
private String decryptString(String string)
    {
        try
        {
            string = getEncryptor().decrypt(string);
        }
        catch (DataLengthException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return string;
    }
```

about 30% of the time I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "53096146ﾝ8}+ﾝ￨￣"
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

The fact that it works sometimes and not others leads me to believe that the decryption takes too long sometimes, and the code continues before it is finished. Could this be it? What  could I do about that?

I get another error about 5% of the time, hard to re-create:

```
InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
```

Would appriciate any info on that too, not sure what it means.

For reference, here is how I initiate the `encryptor`:

```
setEncryptor(new TripleDesCipher());
ripleDesKeyGenerator generator = new TripleDesKeyGenerator();
byte[] key = generator.decodeKey("jdkreur74832904ufke3382r2o3ijf9w");
getEncryptor().setKey(key);
```

Please let me know if you need more info to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] key = generator.decodeKey("jdkreur74832904ufke3382r2o3ijf9w");
```

This method expects a HEX string as input. So your key seems to be invalid to me. (unless you replaced it with invalid garbage here) Thus it causes the encryption and decyrption to fail.

Also 3DES requires keys to be between 1-24 bytes in length. If it is longer, it could cause issues.

And, the InvalidCipherTextException :pad block corrupted : most encryption schemes adds some random/semi random bytes at the end so the length is a multiple of a suitable number for the algorithm (like 16 or 32). If you somehow get this error, it probably means, the last part of the encrypted text is either missing or corrupted.

**UPDATE**

Below are the source code links for TripleDesGenerator, Hex and HexEncoder classes. If you follow them, you will see it generates something unexpected for non-hex inputs:
https://github.com/surevine/gwt-crypto/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gwt/crypto/client/TripleDesKeyGenerator.java
https://github.com/surevine/gwt-crypto/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gwt/crypto/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Hex.java
https://github.com/surevine/gwt-crypto/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gwt/crypto/bouncycastle/util/encoders/HexEncoder.java

Since you have solved your issue using a syncronized method, I assume your initial problem was because of some threading issue. But as far as I see, the above issue still holds.

Comment: I fixed it by making decryptString() synchronized. Wasn't waiting for it to finish. does not need to be HEX value.